# writing QList<int> to file

Tags: c++, qt, file

So here is a little piece of code for writing some information to file

```
void Receiver::fileWrite1(int dd, int mm, int yy, int h, int m, int s, QString commandID, QList<int> parameters)
{
    QString v = "Date - ";
    QString w = "Time - ";
    QString port = "Port = ";
    QString x = "Command = ";
    QString y = "Parameters = ";

    QFile file("E:/practica/data.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::Append)) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open file for writing: "
                  << qPrintable(file.errorString()) << std::endl;

        return;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << v << dd << "/" << mm << "/" << yy << "\r\n";
    out << w << h << " : " << m << " : " << s << "\r\n";
    out << port << c << "\r\n";
    out << x << commandID << "\r\n";
    out << y << << parameters << "\r\n";
    out << "\r\n";
}
```

The problem is, that "parameters" is dynamic and can change it's amount of members and QTextStream is incompactible with QList

Comment: So couldn't you use a for loop to iterate over each int in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can add the contents of the parameters one by one in the required format by iterating the `QList<int>`
2. Depending on the format you want the parameter contents to apppear, try some thing like this

   ```
   QTextStream out(&file);
   out << v << dd << "/" << mm << "/" << yy << "\r\n";
   out << w << h << " : " << m << " : " << s << "\r\n";
   out << port << c << "\r\n";
   out << x << commandID << "\r\n";
   out << y;
   //Iterate through your QList and write the contents
   for(int i=0;i<parameters.length();i++){
   out<< QString::number(parameters.value(i));
   out << "Parameter Seperator here";
   }

   out<< "\r\n";
   out << "\r\n";
   ```